# Android BluetoothAdapter getRemoteDevice is cached

Tags: android, bluetooth

I am developing an Android application, where I use Bluetooth Low Energy.
My code logic includes using the BluetoothAdapter and method getRemoteDevice(MAC-adddress).

The problem is that when I use this method, Android seems to have cached it. Because when I am not close or the device is not on, it still creates the BluetoothDevice-object with the name and all that. But I cannot connect ofcourse.

How can I prevent Android from caching this old BluetoothDevice?

I have tried reflection with

`Method m = device.getClass().getMethod("removeBond", (Class[]) null);
 m.invoke(device, (Object[]) null);`

But it wont yield any better result.

Thank you!

Comment: the same code worked perfectly fine for me. May be you need to test in different brand devices. Bluetooth code behaves differently on each brand.

Comment: Did you find a solution to this problem eventually?

Comment: @IgorGanapolsky No, I have not found any solution for this. I ended up using a timeout function to abort the connection if the "found" device is not responding within a limit.

Answer (score 1):

According to [the documentation for getRemoteDevice](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothAdapter.html#getRemoteDevice(java.lang.String)):

> A BluetoothDevice will always be returned for a valid hardware
>   address, even if this adapter has never seen that device.

So, it is not caching the result, it is just creating a dumb BluetoothDevice object, which has no idea if that MAC address even exists.

You could attempt to connect to the GATT service of the device, or start discovery, or use the LE scanner object, and use the appropriate callback to check if the connection has succeeded or not.